# OData post using odata4j missing "category" element

Tags: java, android, odata, odata4j

I'm attempting to make an Odata post using odata4j.   After dumping the posted xml data, I copied it into a php script using curl just to test.  I found out that the xml post is missing the "category" element which is required for a post.

I can't seem to figure out the appropriate method, looking at the odata4j javadocs, to be able to create this element within the entity structure.

Any thoughts on this?   I've posted a slightly simplified version of my code.

```
// create the new request object
OCreateRequest<OEntity> createRequest = consumer.createEntity( "ESvcOrderTrans" )           
        .properties( OProperties.int32( cursorWrapper.getColumnName(0), cursorWrapper.getInt(0))
        .properties( OProperties.string( cursor.getColumnName(1), cursor.getString(1) ));

// Execute the OData post
OEntity newMaterial = createRequest.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no api for this in the 0.4 release.

One possible workaround is to create a custom OClientBehavior and hack up the request entry messages as they go out.  See http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/wiki/Extensibility

We'll make this easier in the next release.  Track via http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/issues/detail?id=48

Hope that helps,
 - john